# Why some brushes don't Dyntopo?

Tags: sculpting, dynamic-topology

Using Blender 2.9, and not sure if this is normal but a couple of brushes don't dyntopo, for example, Smooth and Draw Sharp. It is kind of frustrating since when I need to draw sharp FOR SURE I need more geometry, as well as it is very useful to change the resolution on some areas by just using the Smooth brush with very little strength.

Thank you in advance.